# render a html string as a normal string in golang

Tags: go

here is my string :

```
test1 = `&lt;iframe src=&quot;https:\/\/www.disnei.com\/embed\/44bc40f3bc04f65b7a35&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;340&quot; scrolling=&quot;no&quot; allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;\/iframe&gt;`
```

and i would like to have the 'normal' string as :

```
<iframe src="https://www.disnei.com/embed/44bc40f3bc04f65b7a35"
```

etc ...

is there a simple way to do it in golang ?

Edit : 
Here are some of my tests : https://play.golang.org/p/OuzNrTXYRB
I still have a blackslash plague

thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `UnescapeString` from the go html lib:
https://godoc.org/html#UnescapeString

Comment: ... or use https://godoc.org/html#UnescapeString from the standard library.

Comment: I still have the \ plague : <iframe src="https:\/\/www.disnei.com\/embed\/44bc40f3bc04f65b7a35"

Comment: @user462794 The "\" are part of the original string. It's not an HTML issue.  What generated the string shown in the question? Perhaps the generator can be modified to avoid adding "\".

Comment: @CeriseLimón I will make a simple string replace but i would like to know if there was something to do it "more simply" thanks btw